# Get all change logs of since last successful build in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins pipeline, I can get change logs of the current build by this.

```
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
```

Is there a way to get all change-logs since last successful build?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
node('my_kubernetes_pod') {
    passedBuilds = []

    lastSuccessfulBuild(passedBuilds, currentBuild);

    def changeLog = getChangeLog(passedBuilds)
    echo "changeLog ${changeLog}"
}

def lastSuccessfulBuild(passedBuilds, build) {
    if ((build != null) && (build.result != 'SUCCESS')) {
        passedBuilds.add(build)
        lastSuccessfulBuild(passedBuilds, build.getPreviousBuild())
    }
}

@NonCPS
def getChangeLog(passedBuilds) {
    def log = ""
    for (int x = 0; x < passedBuilds.size(); x++) {
        def currentBuild = passedBuilds[x];
        def changeLogSets = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets
        for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
            def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
            for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def entry = entries[j]
                log += "* ${entry.msg} by ${entry.author} \n"
            }
        }
    }
    return log;
}
```

Additionally, you may try out "Changes Since Last Success Plugin":
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Changes+Since+Last+Success+Plugin

But it will not work together with pipeline, this is a separate approach.

Comment: It seems this solution gives the change logs of last succesaful builds. What I actually was looking for was chnage logs (of last unsuccessful builds) since last successful build. But your answr is definitely helpful. Build.getpreviousebuuld() and recursion was what i had missed. Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Always welcome ;-)

Comment: I suspect that the recursive solution might run into problems running out of stack if you had it going through a lot of builds. Wouldn't be too hard to switch to an iterative process though.

Answer (score 2):

As I found may be this will helps you. With this you can fetch latest successful build change log file of any project build with Jenkins.

```
$DirectoryA = "D:\Jenkins\jobs\projectName\builds"  ####Jenkind directory
$firstfolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $DirectoryA | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$DirectoryB = $DirectoryA + "\" + $firstfolder

$sVnLoGfIle = $DirectoryB + "\" + "changelog.xml" 

write-host $sVnLoGfIle
```

Comment: In Jenkins\jobs\projectName\builds\75\ I don't see the last changelog file but on the Jenkins dashboard, I see the last-changes option and changes so where to find exactly this last-change file?

Comment: Hey @Ashish, You can find jenkins home directory path "http//:ip:8080/jenkins/configure". In that directory there must be a job`s folder. Changes reflect only for jobs not for any pipeline. 75 is just a build id into that folder you can see "changelog.xml" file